# Testing with Turnip & Capybara, how to click button by class/id/value etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, acceptance-testing, turnip

I'm working with someone else's acceptance tests and I don't quite understand how they work. On the page I have two buttons with the value 'Update' so I'm getting an ambiguity error.

```
  Scenario: Update
When I fill in "line_items__quantity" with "3"
And I click "Update"
Then page should have content "Your cart has been updated"
And "Example Product" should have quantity "3"
```

I'd like to make it so that the logic goes

```
And I click "Update" within :some_div
```

or

```
And I click "update-with-coupon-code"
```

update-with-coupon-code being the button's id.

I just can't figure out the proper syntax to do this. Do I need to do something inside of the steps to make this work? I haven't worked with acceptance tests before. Are there any tutorials that anyone recommends for me to get a better understanding of how they work?

Thanks!

Edit: Code for button (Slim)

First Update button:
    div.cart-buttons
          - [:update, :empty].each do |button|
            = order_form.button value: button
              = t button

Second Update button:

```
section.coupon
      h3 = t(:cart_coupon_code)
      - if @order.has_coupon_code?
        = order_form.text_field :coupon_code, disabled: true
      - else
        = order_form.text_field :coupon_code, placeholder: t(:coupon_code)
        = order_form.button value: :update_with_coupon_code
          = t :update
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, using the button's unique id should be adequate.  Can you please put the code for the button in your question?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I actually thought the acceptance test was written with Cucumber but it was actually Turnip. Everything makes a lot more sense now! Thanks.